# Проверка на пустоту ответа от сервера

Tags: php

Как проверить на пустоту, если приходит такой ответ

```
{
    "response": {
        "players": [

        ]

    }
}
```

Что вышло у меня, но не работает

```
    $GetPlayerSummaries = @file_get_contents("http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=5BC0F61DCDAFEDB5E0DB2A80D0D1280E&steamids=7656");
$PlayerSummaries = (array) json_decode($GetPlayerSummaries) -> response -> players[0];
```

Мне надо проверить `players == 0` да или нет

Comment: Как видно `players` это массив, и он может быть полным или пустым, надо проверить массив пуст или нет. Вот примеры `count(players) == 0`, `isset(players[0])`.

Comment: дак может стоит `json_decode` сделать прежде чем что-либо проверять?

Comment: @teran Зачем `json_decode`? Я что то не так понимаю? Это ведь объект а не строка. http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php

Comment: @StackOverflow потому что `file_get_contents` возвращает текст в формате `json`, и сам он в массивы и объекты не превратится?

Comment: @StackOverflow  от сервера получают именно строку. Тут она приведена отформатированная при просмотре в бразуере видимо, это не вывод var_dump/print_r

Comment: @teran Да спасибо этот момент упустил в вопросе. Но тогда вопрос к автору. как он получил тот объект который дал в примеры?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$GetPlayerSummaries = @file_get_contents("http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=5BC0F61DCDAFEDB5E0DB2A80D0D1280E&steamids=7656");
$PlayerSummaries = (array) json_decode($GetPlayerSummaries) -> response -> players;
if (empty($PlayerSummaries)) {
    /* проверяем функцией empty пустой ли массив и если он пустой, то выполняем условие */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Лучше передавать второй параметр true в json_decode. Тогда создается не объект, а массив и такие вещи проверяются проще - в зависимости от потребности, использовать можно empty, count, is_array.

В данном случае примерно так:

```
$str = '{
    "response": {
        "players": [

        ]

    }
}';

$data = json_decode($str, true);

if (empty($data['response']['players']))
    echo 'empty';
else
    echo 'not empty';
```